# How to redirect all wrong URL to login page?

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes

I want to redirect all wrong URLs that people type in (e.g., www.website.com/xwfkjdf, the pages that don't exist), to the login page (if they're not logged in) and to the dashboard if they're logged in.

Currently, I get "NotFoundHttpException" error.

Comment: And what does your code look like?

Comment: You can do that with Handler.php :
 [https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/how-can-i-redirect-all-request-of-notfoundhttpexception-to-the-home-page](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/how-can-i-redirect-all-request-of-notfoundhttpexception-to-the-home-page)

Comment: Yes, @MeeraTank, it works just the way I wanted. Thank you so much!

This worked: I added this line to the app/Exceptions/Handler.php file:

if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

Comment: @lewis4u thanks for your advice, but once before i answer question like you suggest and someone deleted my answer by saying it should be in comment :/

Answer (score 1):

Change your `render` function inside  `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` to

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    //redirect if route is not found
    if ($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException){
        return redirect('/');
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```